# Reordering levels for multiple factor variables

Tags: r

I'm looking to apply the following code to my data frame  called factored but rather than isolating one variable I'd like to identify multiple ones:

```
factored$DIABETES_FAMILY <- factor(factored$DIABETES_FAMILY, levels=c("Yes","No","Missing"))
```

Currently the order is incorrect as "Missing" , "No", "Yes"
I have many variables with this incorrect order so for example I tried executing this command for two columns as follows but it turned all my observations into NA

```
factored[,2:3] <- factor(factored[,2:3], levels = c("Yes", "No" , "Missing"))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

We need to loop over the columns and assign it to the columns as `factor`  as the `x` argument for `factor` takes a `vector`.

> x- a vector of data, usually taking a small number of distinct values.

based on the documentation (`?factor`)

```
factored[2:3] <- lapply(factored[2:3], factor, levels = c("Yes", "No" , "Missing"))
```